# Dynamic stdout in Haskell

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface

I have simple command line interface with insertion records in DB and
now it writes a lot of info to stdout, like this:

```
...    
record 856/1000: 85%
record 857/1000: 85%
record 858/1000: 85%
...
```

but I want to have 1 dynamic line with updating current string parameters

```
 status         |T    | C   | A   | E
 ---------------------------------------
   inserting    |1000 | 857 | 85% | 96
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [`ncurses`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses) or some higher-level progressbar library like [this](https://github.com/yamadapc/haskell-ascii-progress) will do, I think.

Comment: I've also heard very good things about [brick](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/brick/).

Comment: Just print a CR - see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31900566/866915

Comment: @fjarri ascii-progress is nice!

Comment: @HaoLian brick seems too much for my needs

Comment: @ErikR also nice solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's just one row, you can use `\r` to rewind the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Here's an example:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    forM_ [10, 9 .. 1] $ \seconds -> do
        printf "\rLaunching missiles in %2d..." (seconds :: Int)
        threadDelay $ 1 * 1000 * 1000
    putStrLn "\nBlastoff!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Joey Hess's `concurrent-output` library is designed for progress output like this (and more complex variations).

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-output

https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/a_tiling_region_manager_for_the_console/